# Robot not overriding variable passed in from command line

Tags: robotframework

I have the following test:

```
*** Test Cases ***

My Test
    ${MY_VAR}     Set Variable    %{MY_VAR=mydefault}
```

If I export `MY_VAR` before running the test it picks that up.

If I don't have the env var set it uses the value `mydefault`.

So far so good, but I was expected to also explicitly override via the command line.

When I pass `--variable MY_VAR=fromcmd` it does not use that value.

Does `%{}` not support overriding with `--variable`?

## Edit

Per answer to this question it looks like environment variable interpolation ignores cli injected variables.

If that's the case then it seems to me like the most readable way to handle this is in a variables.py with regular Python code like this (I think it's preferable to handling it with the robot syntax in the test case itself):

```
if not BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${MY_VAR}"):
    MY_VAR = os.environ.get("MY_VAR", "default value")
```

It would be awesome though if there was some way to override this behavior. Does robot provide a way to hook into its `%{}` function and modify it with custom behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true the variable setting in the command line has the highest priority, but this is not what happens here - in this line you are effectively re-setting the value.

You passed some value from the CLI, but when the execution got to that line, it actually did *"the variable MY_VAR will now be set to the value of the env variable MY_VAR, or if there isn't such - to mydefault"*.
E.g. you're effectively overriding the value from the CLI args, present or not.

---

You can solve for this by first checking is the var already defined (from CLI, or some place else), and fall back to env and default only if not. The `Get Variable Value` returns by default `None` (the py type) if a variable is not defined, so using that:

```
${MY_VAR}=    Get Variable Value    ${MY_VAR}
IF    $MY_VAR is None      # not set yet? 
    ${MY_VAR}=   Set Variable    %{MY_VAR=mydefault} 
END
```

Comment: Eek thats disappointing. If thats so then the `%{}` syntax is not very useful to me. I was only using it as a more readable shorthand instead of doing this in a variables.py. Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: Well, to put it in context - how would you solve the same in a programming language, java for example, or python? In your edit you did pretty much the same in py; and RF can be treated as a basic language itself.

Comment: I would just prefer the readability of a single `%{}` assignment. It feels like unexpected behavior that it doesn't support cli var inputs when `${}` does. For something analogous look at makefile. In a Makefile I can say `MY_VAR?=default` and thats it. Explicitly setting the value always takes precedence, then env var lookup, then it falls back on the default. I see this as more RFs configuration handling features then raw programming.

Answer (score 1):

*(Answer #2, having ran into the same myself just this week :)*

Doing in the way you've quoted in the question effectivley overrides the value due to the assignment (see my other answer), but there is another way - just define it in the Variables section:

```
*** Variables *** 
${MY_VAR}=      %{MY_VAR=mydefault}
```

When done here, *(as you are not forcefully re-setting the var: )* the normal RF priority rules kick in - it'll get the value from the env variable, if there isn't such the default will be used, and if you pass an explicit one through CLI - it'll override both.